# In an ER diagram, can an entity know information about a non-directly connected entity?

Tags: database-diagrams, entity

Imagine a simple database like this:

```
[credit card] --- has --- [customer] --- places --- [order]
```

Of course the order would know which customer placed it, but would it know which credit card the customer used to place it?

Would the credit card and order entity sets need a direct relationship for this to be knowable?

Another variation on this question:

```
[customer] ---places--- [order] ---funded_by--- [credit card]
```

Now obviously the order knows which credit card was used, but is there now no link between a customer and a credit card? (i.e. no way to get a list of all the credit cards owned by a given customer?)

Comment: Looks like you're missing the "Payment" entity.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could have a credit_card table and then a joining table (more properly known as an [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) - (there are 16 other possible names listed) customer_cc entity listing customer_id and credit_card_id? I'm not sure that it's a good idea to store credit card details unless you're really quite the expert in security/data protection APIs/encryption...